# Is it possible to search Scopus API between certain coverDates?

Tags: api-design, scopus

I'm trying to create an application that lists research article entries from Scopus between two set dates (and does things with them - irrelevant for the current question). As I understand it, there is a "date" param that can be added to the search address for the Scopus API, but that can only be used for years (?). Every entry in Scopus however comes with a coverDate, which includes month and day. However, I am unable to work out how to restrict results to a specified coverDate period.

Of course, I can always retrieve all entries from the years that the period covers and then do the filtering in the app. However, that generates a lot of redundancy, so would be good to not use that work-around.

Have tried different Y-m-d formats for the &date param without success, as well as the pubyear query. I have now also tried to add PUBDATETXT() to the query, where I add several months (March+2022+OR+April+2022 etc), but Scopus interprets that as journals that have several of the dates as their coverdate.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
?query=ISSN(2376-6662) OR ISSN(2330-5517) AND PUBYEAR > 2018 AND PUBYEAR < 2023
```

Source: https://dev.elsevier.com/data-fetcher-resources/DataFetcherManual_7_4_3.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the answer to the same question, and the following was my solution on how to include the year in my search:

Below is an example to search all articles with query= "dry reforming of methane" and published in 2019:

'https://api.elsevier.com/content/search/sciencedirect?start=800&count=100&query=dry reforming of methane&date=2019&apiKey=(--)&insttoken=(--)'

OR for multiple years:

'https://api.elsevier.com/content/search/sciencedirect?start=800&count=100&query=dry reforming of methane&date=2019-2020&apiKey=(--)&insttoken=(--)'

Reference: https://dev.elsevier.com/documentation/SCOPUSSearchAPI.wadl